# SSIS-job that executes SAS-scripts suddenly stopped working (but appears to run successfully)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sas

We have a daily SSIS-job that runs in 3 SQL Server environments. The job runs an SSIS-project that executes multiple SAS-scripts (stored on a SAS-server per SSIS-environment).

There's never been any problems with this SSIS-project, until now. Although the SSIS-jobs appears to run well and appears to execute the SAS-scripts (they complete with successful status), **the scripts don't actually get executed** (on any of the SAS-servers).

According to the Execution Log in SSMS, each SAS-script is successfully executed. However it says that each script finished in under 1 second (a successful execution normally takes many minutes). And on the SAS-server side we don't find any trace of the scripts having been run (no log files are generated). [SSMS log example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJI2h.png)

The SAS-scripts were successfully executed on Monday (and each day before that, for multiple years). We haven't changed the SSIS-project or the SAS-scripts in any way since then. And there apparently haven't been any changes to our infrastructure, network, drivers, etc. Not for SAS, nor for SQL Server. At least not according to anyone we've been in touch with so far...

It appears as though SSIS thinks it's communicating with SAS, while SAS ignores SSIS. And there's no errors or warnings.

If I try to execute a SAS-script manually by running an individual SSIS-package, the same thing happens: It appears to run well, but doesn't actually execute the SAS-program.

The SAS-scripts are stored on a SAS-server, and run via Execute Process tasks in SSIS-packages. The arguments use the following script (unchanged for 3 years):

```js
 #!/bin/sh
 dtstamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H.%M.%S)
 sas_dir=/opt/sas94/$1/sashome/SASFoundation/9.4
 script_dir="/data/DVHANALYSE/scripts/projects/monaco/current/sas_code"
 log_dir="/data/DVHANALYSE/scripts/logs/monaco"
    
 suff=".sas"
 echo "This is running Monaco $2"
    
 echo "env: $1" >> $log_dir/plink.log
 echo "pgm: $2" >> $log_dir/plink.log
    
 pgmname=$2
 logname=${pgmname%"$suff"}"_$dtstamp.log"
    
 #
 $sas_dir/sas $script_dir/$pgmname -log $log_dir/$logname
 #exit 0
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

EDIT: I've enabled full logging on one of the SSIS-packages and executed it. As you can see on row 19, the process simply exits now: [SSIS Logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k21zK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that the SAS license is expired.

Comment: Thanks, but those same SAS-servers are mainly used for our SAS data warehouse, and we haven't experienced any issues with that. We also have business users who use SAS Enterprise Guide without any problems. It's only the SSIS-SAS 'relationship' that's causing troubles.

Comment: You bave to get the SAS log. It is on the server. What does $logname file contain?

Comment: Even though the SSIS-logging says that the SAS-scripts are executed, nothing actually happens on the  SAS-server anymore. Not since the last successful batch on Monday. No scripts are executed, and no log files are generated. It's as though SSIS thinks it's communicating with SAS, while SAS is actually giving SSIS the cold shoulder.

Comment: You are asking for a boolean answer. Answer is I did that but so what. Ran the process but it came back failed. You need to find the failure so you need to find the root. Keep digging to the sas log. Sas absolutely sucks at return error codes. What you will get from stdout is probably failed

Comment: I looked at issue from the image. If you are using putty, use it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

- We switched to SHA256-hostkeys (for communication between SSIS & SAS).
- The Microsoft server (which was running putty/plink v.0.70) was upgraded to v.0.75 (which supports SHA256).